Get the intersection points of the boundary of the region along with an oriented curve in order
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
   Text[Style["℘", Bold, FontFamily -> "Times"]], _Text];
plot = ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], t*Sin[t]}, {t, -6, 6}];
Show[reg, plot]


We can see that the oriented curve intersection the font ℘ with 6 points. I want to get the coordinate of the 6 points respect to the direction of the curve.
The first and the last points seems to be {{-0.078, 1.64}, ..., {-0.728, -2.67}}
BTW, the parametric curve maybe any other curve, for example, see the animation.
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
  Text[Style["℘", Bold, 
    FontFamily -> "Times"]], _Text];
 Manipulate[
 Show[reg, ParametricPlot[t*{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, -6, s}], 
  PlotRange -> 5], {s, -5, 6}]


Interesting question. In the case of Mathematica Version 14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM, there are only four intersection points :-)

By the way, is it important that the parameter range is [-6,6] rather than [0,6]?

@A.Kato We can  consider the updated example. [-6,6] or [0,6] is not so important, we can set another range.


SignedRegionDistance do the job.
But my code only work for the updated example, not for the first example since there are extra values of the parametric t.

Clear["Global`*"];
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
   Text[Style["℘", Bold, FontFamily -> "Times"]], _Text];
dist = SignedRegionDistance@reg;
plot1 = ParametricPlot[t  {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, -6, 6}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, dist@{x, y} < 0], 
   PlotStyle -> Yellow];
plot2 = ParametricPlot[t  {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, -6, 6}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, dist@{x, y} > 0], 
   PlotStyle -> Cyan];
plot3 = ParametricPlot[t {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, -6, 6}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, t}, dist[t {Cos[t], Sin[t]}]]}, 
   Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Red, PlotStyle -> None];
tvalues = 
 MeshCoordinates[
    DiscretizeRegion[
     ImplicitRegion[dist[t   {Cos[t], Sin[t]}] == 0, {t}]]] // 
   Flatten // Sort
g = Graphics[
   MapIndexed[
    Text[Style[Last@#2, FontSize -> 16], 
      Function[{t}, t  {Cos[t], Sin[t]}]@#1] &, tvalues]];
Show[reg, plot1, plot2, plot3, g]


{-2.74912, -2.21741, -0.583719, 0.378264, 1.64061, 1.82213, 2.23373, \ 2.74418}



FindInstance can get some t but NSolve can not get any solution.

FindInstance[dist[t {Cos[t], Sin[t]}] == 0, {t}, Reals, 10]


{{t -> 0.378264}, {t -> -2.74912}, {t ->  1.82213}, {t -> -2.21741}, {t -> 2.74418}, {t ->  2.23373}, {t -> -0.583719}, {t -> -2.74912}, {t -> 1.64061}, {t ->  2.23373}}


For the first example, we have to limit the range since the curve turn back.

tvalues = 
  MeshCoordinates[
     DiscretizeRegion[
      ImplicitRegion[dist[{Cos[t], t*Sin[t]}] == 0, {t}]]] // 
    Flatten // Sort;
tvalues = Select[tvalues, -6 < # < 1 &]


{-3.89678, -3.25197, -2.96861, -2.67844, -1.99205, -1.66586}



Another way.

Clear["Global`*"];
reg1 = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
   Text[Style["℘", Bold, FontFamily -> "Times"]], _Text];
reg2 = DiscretizeRegion@
   ParametricRegion[{Cos[t], t*Sin[t]}, {{t, 0, 6}}];
reg12 = RegionIntersection[reg2, reg1];
list = MeshCells[reg12, 1][[;; , 1]];
indexes = (Flatten /@ 
      Split[list, Last[#1] == First[#2] &])[[;; , {1, -1}]] // Flatten;
pts = MeshCoordinates[reg12][[Flatten@indexes]]
Graphics[{{LightOrange, reg1}, MeshPrimitives[reg2, 1], 
  MapIndexed[{Red, Point[#1], 
     Text[Style[First@#2, 16, Blue], #1, {-1, -1}]} &, pts]}]



thank you for very instructive answer illustrating region functionality. +1 :)

@ubpdqn Thanks.  I don’t know why NSolve does not work.
